# What are these orange lid separators on chips of the motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard, lid

From what I've googled, the motherboards aren't assembled by hand so these lids are put to prevent the heatsink from contacting the chips. My question is what are these lids technically called? For example if I want to buy this type of lid, what do I ask for in the store? Because the glue residue on the lids is completely removed so I need to buy replacements.

[image]

The chips are huge, if I don't put the lid back, I would have to use A LOT of thermal paste to prevent heatsink contacting the chip.

[image]

Comment: Does it look similar to the subject of [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/7qs28q/orange_plastic_on_processor_and_gpu/)?

Comment: Yes! It does! @harrymc

Comment: Shall I put up an answer about it?

Comment: so its a jig for applying thermal paste with reckless abandon. nice.

Comment: @harrymc yes please and thank you.

Comment: The actual material looks like kapton, which is a heat resistant plastic used a lot in electronics manufacturing

Comment: Oh so it's called kapton tape! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the post
[Orange plastic on processor and GPU](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/7qs28q/orange_plastic_on_processor_and_gpu/):

> As for the plastic covers, they're there to aid in quicker assembly by preventing the paste from spreading on to anything other then the dies. As you can see they don't always work that well. But in theory a worker puts the plastic down, slaps the TIM on any heat producing surfaces and then puts the all-in-one heat sink on top and tightens it down.

And also :

> if i do maintainance to a laptop, and i encounter stuff like this i would remove the yellow plastic. That yellow plastic is only there so that the assembly factory can work at high speed blobbing paste all over and put the heatsink on.
>
> You do have to be carefull if the adhesive underneath the yellow plastic is stiff. you can rip an transistor off.